# Hide external namespaces in doxygen generated documentation

Tags: namespaces, documentation, doxygen, package, documentation-generation

How can I hide non-documented namespaces. I have added to my documentation the Android documentation (with a android.tag file). However now I've many undocumentated namespaces (packages) which I would like to hide. See also this screenshot:

[image: Namespace overview]

Where you can see some of my documentated classes, but there are also many namespaces which are not docmentated (and also external) how can I hide them?

Comment: These namespaces should not appear in the index. There was a bug in doxygen that caused them to appear, but I think this is fixed in the meantime. Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @doxygen sorry I forgot to answer. I'm using Doxygen 1.8.5 on Windows (if this matters). I generated the whole documentation for android and wrote a small tool which replaced all local references to the correct online android documentation. Not sure if this causes the problem I also get some wired warnings in the console about unexpected attributes.

Comment: You can see that tag file here: https://gist.github.com/rekire/7675412 if this file causes the bug please guide me how to avoid that.

Comment: I have the same problem on linux with doxygen 1.8.5. @doxygen, could you maybe point me to the mentioned bug, I couldn't find it on bugzilla. Including the external namespaces to EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I have this problem even in 1.8.6

Comment: Try the latest version from GitHub. You need this commit to fix the problem: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/1bdbbc60982f2f61f4e0423c9fc8c4a24cfb2e94

Comment: @doxygen Is it possible that you upload the binaries somewhere? Currently I cannot compile that project by my own for Windows. I'm sure that is not your preferred way, but I guess you need to enter just one command for building the binaries.

Comment: Try this: ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/test/doxygen-1.8.6-20140107.windows.bin.zip

Comment: @doxygen Perfect that works fine :) Add a notice as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is known and an unofficial fix (which was verified to work) is available here:
ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/test/doxygen-1.8.6-20140107.windows.bin.zip

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Is there any workaround for Linux? Or is the fix going to be integrated into future releases?

Comment: link does not work, what a bad answer.